# Simple Login w/ Role for Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

Most of the posts I've read about authentication for Slim Framework are oriented to API Basic Authentication.

I just need a simple login/logout with role, but I'm confused about how to implement some kind of middleware. The web isn't intented to be for production.

These are my login routes so far,

```
$app->get('/login', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('login.html');
})->name('login-form');


$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
    $req = $app->request;

    $user= $req->params('user');
    $pass = $req->params('pass');

    try {
        $query = $app->db->prepare("SELECT user, pass FROM users
                              WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass
                              LIMIT 1");
        $query->execute(
            array(
                ':user' => $user,
                ':pass' => md5($pass)
            )
        );

        $result = $query->fetch();
    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $app->flash('error', 'db error');
    }


    if ( empty($result) ) {
        $app->flash('error', 'wrong user or pass');
        $app->redirect('/login');
    }

    $app->redirect('/');

})->name('login');
```

Comment: What kind of middleware are you trying to do? You could use [slim-auth](https://github.com/jeremykendall/slim-auth) if you need a cool authorization and authentication library.

Comment: Kind of a shameless plug, but I've been reworking my authorization/user management framework to use Slim: https://github.com/alexweissman/UserFrosting/tree/dev-0.3.0.  We already have a data model and login/logout routes implemented.  Feel free to take what you like and leave the rest.